# SSRS Report Group by destination, then by Year , then by Month and then by day

Tags: ssrs-2012

I am attempting write a report with a summary by location.  However, the groupings are duplicating.  Need to see single location name with total entries.  In the example it should show Athens in 2023, month 1 and day 2 I should have a total of 2.

[image]

[image]

Required output

[image]

I grouped by destination (parent group), then by year (parent group), then by month (parent group), then by day (parent group).  I want to see each location, by year, month and day as a single total entry.  Instead it is splitting out each entry.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all your fields are inside the details group (the lowest level), you can see this by the the horizontal lines in the row header. You only need a single group that groups by location/year/month/day unless you also want total by month and year?

If you only need the day level totals then remove all rowgroups except 1 and then edit the remaining row group to group by the 4 fields as required.

If you want to retain the location/year/month groups so you can add totals to those, try deleting the details rowgroup.

If this does not help, explain what totals you need and show the rowgroup panel (below the main designer window)

Comment: The 2nd image is my current result.  The 3rd image i added to show you what I want as my results.

Comment: You didn't show the rowgroup panel from the design view but you probably just need to delete the details rowgroup.